# cookie to remember dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, drop-down-menu

I have a simple dropdown  and user selects a choice and the page refreshes with the selection added to the URL as a querystring. But i want to also keep the selected state of dropdown after the refresh. How do i do that using jquery or cookie?

```
<select id="MyDropDown" onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')">

  <option value="http://mysite.com/default1.aspx?alpha=A">A</option>
  <option value="http://mysite.com/default1.aspx?alpha=B">B</option>
  <option value="http://mysite.com/default1.aspx?alpha=C">C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: jquery.cookie ? http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Comment: Does the site need to popup on refresh too? If not, you will need a "Please select" option, but then you do not need the cookie

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jquery cookie plugin and write code as shown below

```
$('#MyDropDown').change(function() {
    $.cookie('mycookie', $(this).val(), {
             expires: 365}
             );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way to save the state without putting data on each html request is to use HTML5 Local storage. 
Here is a good example how to use it: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-learning-about-html5-local-storage/

Answer (score 0):

Does setting a cookie not work?

```
<select id="MyDropDown" onchange="document.cookie=this.selectedIndex; window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')">
```

You could also just extract the value of "alpha" passed with the URL.