# document cookie to remember dropdown selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, drop-down-menu, selection

How do I use document cookie function to make browser remember the user selected dropdown after the page is refreshed? On change of selection, the browser refreshes itself with extra parameter added to the URL but restores the default dropdown option instead of user selected one..

```
<select id="MyDropDown" onchange="document.cookie=this.selectedIndex; window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')">
    <option value="http://mysite.com/default1.aspx?alpha=A">A</option>
      <option value="http://mysite.com/default1.aspx?alpha=B">B</option>
      <option value="http://mysite.com/default1.aspx?alpha=C">C</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Didn't you already [ask this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745328/cookie-to-remember-dropdown-selection) ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer by bebonham worked, but only for up to 9 options in the dropdown list.  I tweaked it such that it worked for longer dropdown lists.

```
<html>
<body>
<select id="MyDropDown" onchange="document.cookie= 'myDDIdx = ' + this.selectedIndex + '; path=/;'; window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')">
<option value="http://example.com/default1.aspx?alpha=A">A</option>
<option value="http://example.com/default1.aspx?alpha=B">B</option>
<option value="http://example.com/default1.aspx?alpha=C">C</option>
</select>

<SCRIPT>
function readCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}
return null;
}


window.onload = function () { document.getElementById("MyDropDown").selectedIndex = readCookie("myDDIdx"); } 
</SCRIPT>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For saving the selection, use this:

```
document.cookie='myselection='+this.selectedIndex;
```

This will make your selection available on the cookie named `myselection`

Write a function to read the cookie and set the saved value and call it on your document's onload. i.e.

```
function setSavedValue() {
    var theCookie=" "+document.cookie;
    var ind=theCookie.indexOf(" myselection=");
    if (ind==-1) ind=theCookie.indexOf(";myselection=");
    if (ind==-1) return "";
    var ind1=theCookie.indexOf(";",ind+1);
    if (ind1==-1) ind1=theCookie.length; 
    return unescape(theCookie.substring(ind+'myselection'.length+2,ind1));
}
```

and call it on your onload like this:

```
<body onload="setSavedValue()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery (or plain old JavaScript) to insert the new select element. Build it inside a form with a normal submit button so that if the user has JavaScript disabled, you just rebuild the HTML on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
  <select id="MyDropDown" onchange="document.cookie= 'myDDIdx = ' + this.selectedIndex + '; path=/;'; window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')">
<option value="http://mysite.com/default1.aspx?alpha=A">A</option>
  <option value="http://mysite.com/default1.aspx?alpha=B">B</option>
  <option value="http://mysite.com/default1.aspx?alpha=C">C</option>
</select>

<script>
    var sidx = document.cookie.indexOf("myDDIdx");
if(sidx != -1)
    window.onload = function () { document.getElementById("MyDropDown").selectedIndex = document.cookie.substr(sidx + 8,1); }
</script>
</body>
```